# Two Dimensional Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've found this tutorial on YouTube where I've been told that `map.map` is somehow a 2D Map and I cannot figure out what he means by that or how this alleged 2D Map is supposed to work.

If I type `:t map.map` into GHCI, I see that it takes in a function and `[[a]]`. I don't know what `[[a]]` means.

Mathematically, $M \circ M = M(f, M(x,y))$. Does this mean I must give `map.map` a function and a map function?

I tried `map.map (\x -> 2*x) ( map (\y -> 3*y) [1,2,3] )` and that didn't work (couldn't match expected type). I don't really know what else to try as I don't understand what it's doing :/

Comment: `[[a]]` is a 2 dimensional array of type `a`. ie an array of arrays of type a

Comment: Hmm… I added an answer but also I’m confused what you’re actually trying to do in your code. What is the input that you have? And what are you trying to do with it? I think you are possibly conflating 2D arrays with 2D space (ie geometry). But they are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Your equation `M \circ M = M(f, M(x,y))` makes no sense to me. I'd instead say that `(M \circ M)(f) = M(M(f))`, and this is indeed what happens in Haskell: `(map . map) f = map (map f)`. Further, we can claim `(map . map) f xss = map (map f) xss` where `xss` is any lists of lists (of type `[[a]]`) while `f :: a -> b` is a function.

Comment: @fogmeister it's probably best to call lists (`[]`) lists instead of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `map.map` is:

```
map.map :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

It takes a function that maps from `a` to `b` and applies it to each element in a list of lists of `a`, returning a list of lists of the results.

Consider:

```
Prelude> let d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] in (map.map) (2 *) d
[[2,4,6],[8,10,12]]
Prelude>
```

When you try:

```
map.map (\x -> 2*x) ( map (\y -> 3*y) [1,2,3] )
```

`map (\y -> 3*y) [1,2,3]` is simply going to return `[3, 6, 9]`. This single dimensional list cannot match the list of lists type that `map.map` is expecting.

*Sidenote:* though it would still be wrong, you might express your attempt as `map.map (2 *) $ map (3 *) [1,2,3]`.

Comment: Thank you. But why doesn't ```map.map (\x -> 2*x) [[1,2],[3,4]]``` work then?

Comment: I recieved errors when trying to use `map.map` on its own. Try using parentheses around the function name as I have in my example.

Comment: @Zulaxs `map.map x y` actually means `map . (map x y)` and does not involve the composition `map.map` in any way. Since `map x y` is a list and not a function, we can't compose it, triggering a type error. You instead want `(map . map) x y` (where `x` is a function and `y` is a list-of-lists).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! It works now.